# How to use a custom build script with golang and react?

Tags: heroku

I have a react frontend in the same repo as my golang server. I need the build process to first build react and then compile and run the server. How can I have it run the build process for react and then the server?

Answer (score 1):

I was using `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` to install the react app in a subdirectory. I removed all of the yarn related files and added a `package.json` file at the top level with a build script that looks like `cd ./client && npm install && npm run build`. The reason I'm doing an `npm install` here is because heroku tries to install dependencies in the top level `package.json` that I made which doesn't have any dependencies in it. This isn't the greatest solution, I'm not really a fan, but it works for now. If anyone has any suggestions on how to do this better, I'd love to know.

I also had to configure two buildpacks on heroku, first the npm one and then the golang one. The one for golang just worked as normal since all of the code is at the top level of the repo. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app